# Django Return File and Template

Tags: python, django

I currently have a view that just returns a word document once the form is submitted. The page/template doesn't change at all.

```
def form_view(request):
    context = dict()

    if request.method == 'POST':
       #do a bunch of things
        http_word_response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
        http_word_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
        doc.save(http_word_response)
        return http_word_response

     else:
       return render( request, 'mysite/form.html', context)
```

I'd like to have it so it return the document like it does, but then update the page from my context dictionary. I know how to return the variables into my template, but I'm having trouble combining it with returning the document.

I tried adding this:

```
return render(request, 'mysite/form.html', context, http_word_response)
```

instead of `return http_word_response` but it returned a document that has literally my entire html template file and did not return the word document.

I'm not against returning a URL or link to download the file if that's what is needed, this way has just always been the easiest since it doesn't save anything on the server side.

EDIT:
I'd like to have this return the document and my context dictionary to the template once submit is hit on my form. Right now it only returns the document.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want the contents of a `.docx` rendered online?

Comment: added an edit. let me know if that clarifies or not

Comment: Appreciated. I'm a Flask user so not sure I can help here but it's a little clearer to me now, I think